# Move files to folder using matching filename

Tags: powershell, python, filesystems, regex

I have doc, docx and PDF files wherein the filenames consist of a unique 9 digit number followed by text.

I want to move those files to their respective folders which also consist of at least the unique 9 digit number but may have different text.

Those folders are in another folder on the hard drive but I can easily move the documents to the same parent folder if needed. The files and folder names are a combination of 123456789_Firstname_Lastname.docx. Instead of underscores, there may be spaces, or commas or no spaces at all. What will be certain though, is that the file and folder name begins with 9 numbers.

I have Python installed, Hazel, and Directory Opus and can install anything else if needed to make this process work. There are thousands of files so I'd really appreciate a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Not a script writing service, but this (untested) PowerShell should get you started:

```
$DestParent = 'C:\NumberedFolders'
Get-ChildItem *.txt, *.pdf | %{
   $ID = $_.BaseName.Substring(0,8)
   $Dest = (Get-Item "$destparent\$ID*").FullName
   Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $Dest
}
```

[Get-ChildItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem)

[ForEach-Object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-6)

[String.Substring Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.8)

[Get-Item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item?view=powershell-6)

[Move-Item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/move-item?view=powershell-6)